# Finding the next in round-robin scheduling by bit twiddling

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, verilog, vhdl

Consider the following problem. You have a bit-string that represents the current scheduled slave in one-hot encoding. For example, "00000100" (with the leftmost bit being #7 and rightmost #0) means that slave #2 is scheduled.

Now, I want to pick the next scheduled slave in a round-robin scheduling scheme, with a twist. I have a "request mask" which says which slaves actually want to be scheduled. The next slave will be picked only from those that want to.

Some examples (assume round-robin scheduling is done by rotating left). 
Example1:

- Current: "00000100"
- Mask: "01100000"
- Next schedule: "00100000" - in normal round-robin, #3 and then #4 should come after #2, but they don't request, so #5 is picked.

Example2:

- Current: "01000000"
- Mask: "00001010"
- Next: "00000010" - because scheduling is done by cycling left, and #1 is the first requesting slave in that order.

---

Now, this can be easily coded in a loop, I know. But I actually want to get my result by a bit-twiddling operation, without loops. The motivation: I want to implement this in hardware (in an FPGA) in VHDL/Verilog.

A bonus is to make up an algorithm that's generic for any amount of slaves N.

By the way, this is not a homework question. It's an important problem whenever one wants to schedule slaves in some manner, and condition the scheduling by the slaves' requests. My current solution is somewhat "heavy" and I wanted to know if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I've come up with a hardware-centered digital logic solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480405/finding-the-next-in-round-robin-scheduling-by-bit-twiddling#486480 This was a very interesting problem! I just couldn't put it down :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the following Verilog code for implementing the task in the Altera advanced synthesis cookbook.

```
// 'base' is a one hot signal indicating the first request
// that should be considered for a grant.  Followed by higher
// indexed requests, then wrapping around.
//

module arbiter (
    req, grant, base
);

parameter WIDTH = 16;

input [WIDTH-1:0] req;
output [WIDTH-1:0] grant;
input [WIDTH-1:0] base;

wire [2*WIDTH-1:0] double_req = {req,req};
wire [2*WIDTH-1:0] double_grant = double_req & ~(double_req-base);
assign grant = double_grant[WIDTH-1:0] | double_grant[2*WIDTH-1:WIDTH];

endmodule
```

It uses subtraction (only once, though), so conceptually it's quite similar to Doug's solution.

Answer (score 6):

A loop does not have to be bad.

I would simply do

```
current[i] = current[i-1] & mask[i] |                         // normal shift logic
                mask[i] & current[i-2] & !mask[i-1] |         // here build logic 
                ...                                          // expression for 
                                                             // remaining
```

And then put it into a generate loop (ie it will get unrolled into hardware), which will produce parallel hardware for the expressions.

Other here mentioned solutions use multiple "-". I can only discourage them, as this will get you a really expensive operation. Esp. in one hot you can get easily more than > 32 bits, which will not easily be implementable in HW, as the borrow has to go through all bits (the deadicated carry logic on certain fpgas make it approachable for small number of bits).

Comment: Agreed, my bit twiddling solution is much less efficient in hardware.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more about the algorithm, it's not obvious! what is "i"? generate loop by what, by "i", i.e. per each bit of the "current" ?

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works for any number of slaves (K), and is O(n) in your FPGA. For each bit in the field, you will require three logic gates and two inverters. I tested out the concept with a basic logic simulator, and it works.

The chain of logic gates between *current* and *mask* essentially creates a priority system that favors bits "lower down" in the chain. This chain is looped at the ends, but the *current* bits are used to break the chain.

To visualize the operation, imagine that bit *3* is set in the *current* field, and follow the signal downwards in the diagram. The logical one at bit *3* places a logical zero at the input to the first AND gate, which guarantees that the output of that AND gate will also be zero (this is where the OR-gate chain is broken). The zero at the output of the first AND gate places a one at the input to the second AND gate. This makes bit *2* of *next* directly dependent on bit *2* of *mask*.

Now, the chain of OR gates comes into play.

If bit *2* of *mask* was set, the logical output of the OR gate directly to the left of it will also be a one, which will place a logical one at the input to the AND gate below bit *2* of *current* (which will be zero, since only one bit in *current* can be set at a time). The logical one at the output of the top AND gate places a logical zero at the input of the bottom AND gate, thus setting bit *1* of *next* equal to zero.

If bit *2* of *mask* was not set, both inputs to the OR gate would be zero, so the output of the AND gate below bit *2* of *current* would be a zero, placing a one at the input to the bottom AND gate, and therefore making bit *1* of *next* dependent on bit *1* of *mask*.

This logic follows the chain of OR gates "up" the bits, looping around from the left side back over to the right, ensuring that only one bit in *next* can be set to a one. The loop stops once it makes its way back to bit *3* of *current*, as a result of that bit being set. This prevents the circuit from staying in a perpetual loop.

I have no experience with Verilog or VHDL, so I'll leave the actual code up to you [and the rest of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486471/how-would-you-implement-this-digital-logic-in-verilog-or-vhdl).

[alt text http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5125/bitshifterlogicdiagramkn7.jpg](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5125/bitshifterlogicdiagramkn7.jpg)

**notes:**

1. This solution is only partial. It will still require some kind of latching mechanism to hold the bit fields.

   Keep in mind that as you increase the number of bits, the time required for the gate voltages to settle will also increase.

   There will have to be some logic in place to handle the case where the *current* field is equal to zero. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486473/how-would-you-handle-a-special-case-in-this-digital-logic-system).

Comment: great solution. but I still see a combinatorial loop here

Comment: although it does happen only when current is all 0s (otherwise it's blocked by some AND), i'm not sure how the synthesizer will take it.

Comment: Yeah, there still needs to be a check for current == 0. Pax suggests a good solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486473/how-would-you-handle-a-special-case-in-this-digital-logic-system

Comment: @eliben: In case you missed it, Marty posted verilog code for this logic in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486471/how-would-you-implement-this-digital-logic-in-verilog-or-vhdl/488863#488863

Answer (score 2):

Assuming twos complement representation, call your two words `mask` and `current`, in C:

```
mask_lo = (current << 1) - 1; // the bits to the right and including current
mask_hi = ~mask_lo;           // the bits to the left of current
                              // the left bits, otherwise right:
next = (mask & mask_hi) ? (mask & mask_hi) : (mask & mask_lo);
return (next & -next);        // the least significant bit set
```

Comment: Downvoted because the algorithm does not work. It will return the lowest bit set mask that is not also set in current. Eg: mask = 01100001, current = 00000100, it will return 00000001

Comment: eJames, are you sure about that? I think it will return 00100000.

Comment: Is the || operator guaranteed to stop after (mask & mask_hi) if that operation turns out to be non-zero?

Comment: As written, next uses || which evaluates to 0 or 1 in C, so the result is either 0 or 1. use next = (mask & mask_hi) ? (mask & mask_hi) : (mask & mask_lo);

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Also, the second line needs to be << 1 instead of << 2

Comment: eJames - you have a point here. If || is used in its C short-circuiting manner, Doug is right. but if it's used in its "hardware" interpretation, you've provided a counter example.

Comment: In all fairness, the idea for the algorithm is sound. I'll edit in the changes and replace my downvote with an upvote.

Comment: though, I guess in hardware one can quite simply implement the short-circuiting "or" as well

Comment: I've made the changes and reversed my vote. I tested the new version with gcc3.4.5 and it works like a charm.

Comment: I've also come up with a logic/hardware solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480405/finding-the-next-in-round-robin-scheduling-by-bit-twiddling#486480

Answer (score 2):

Subracting 1 is the essential idea here. It's used to cascade borrows through the bits to find the next task.

```
bits_before_current = ~(current-1) & ~current
bits_after_current = current-1
todo = (mask & bits_before_current) 
if todo==0: todo = (mask & bits_after_current) // second part is if we have to wrap around
next = last_bit_of_todo = todo & -todo
```

This will use a loop internally though...

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem!  I can't help but wonder if you can't simplify your scheduler operation so this sort of operation would be necessary.

Given that you know VHDL, I won't go into detail, but my suggestion would be the following:

Use a 3 bit encoder to turn the currently scheduled task into a number:

01000000 --> 6

Then use a barrel shifter to rotate the mask by that number + 1 (to skip the current task):

00001010 --> 00010100

Then use a priority encoder to find the first available "next" task:

00010100 --> 00000100 --> 2

Then reverse the barrel shift by addition:

(2+7) % 8 = 1

Which when re-encoded will give the next scheduled task:

00000010

Should be very fast and straightforward, although the barrel shifter is 'expensive' in terms of realestate, but I don't see an easy way to get around that at the moment.

Edit: Doug's solution is significantly more elegant...

-Adam

Comment: this is very close to what I had in mind. But apart from the barrel shifter, the priority encoder is also quite expensive, isn't it?

Comment: A priority encoder isn't cheap, but it's smaller than a barrel shifter.  Still, the solutions presented in other answers should yield a smaller overall solution, although the ideal VHDL compiler will do the karnaugh map analysis and minimize every solution to the same small equation...

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
number_of_tasks= <number of tasks, in the example this is 8>
next_mask= current | (current - 1);
next_barrel= next | (next << number_of_tasks);
next_barrel&= ~number_of_tasks;
next_barrel&= -next_barrel;
next_barrel|= next_barrel >> number_of_tasks;
next_task_mask= next_barrel & -next_barrel;
```

Basically, duplicate the bits of the next task mask, mask off the bits we don't want to consider, find the lowest set bit, fold the high bits back in, then take the lowest bit set. This runs in constant time.

Edit: Updating to take into account current == 00010000 and next_mask == 00111000

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but off the top of my head, I'd be surprised if this didn't produce ma reasonable synthesis... Has the advantage of being relatively readable (to me anyway) unlike typical bit-twiddling hacks.

```
for i in current'range loop
  current := rotate_left(current, 1);
  if or_reduce(mask and current) = '1' then
     current:= mask and current;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete parametrizable arbiter implementation that can be configured for round-robin or priority arbitration:

https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-axis/blob/master/rtl/arbiter.v

This design uses a pair of priority encoders to select the next output in the sequence.  The priority encoders used are implemented efficiently as trees.