# How would you implement this digital logic in Verilog or VHDL?

Tags: logic, hardware, vhdl, verilog

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480405/finding-the-next-in-round-robin-scheduling-by-bit-twiddling#486480) to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480405/finding-the-next-in-round-robin-scheduling-by-bit-twiddling) which requires some digital logic to be implemented in Verilog or VHDL so that it can be programmed into an FPGA.

**How would you implement the following logic diagram in Verilog, VHDL, or any other hardware description language?**

The numbered boxes represent bits in a field. Each field has *K* bits, and the bits for *current* and *mask* will be provided by a computer system (using a latched register or equivalent). The bits in *next* will be read back into that same computer system.

[alt text http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5125/bitshifterlogicdiagramkn7.jpg](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5125/bitshifterlogicdiagramkn7.jpg)

See also: [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486473/how-would-you-handle-a-special-case-in-this-digital-logic-system)

Comment: FYI, image link is (now) broken.

Comment: @luis.espinal it shows up fine for me, but I know for a fact that many corporate web filters (WebSense, for example) will filter out third party images.

Comment: DOH! That's what it is, I'm looking at this from within my corporate network. Never mind and thanks :)

Comment: No worries. I hate those filters, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
module scheduler
 #( parameter K = 10 )
  (
   input wire [K:1] current,
   input wire [K:1] mask,
   output reg [K:1] next
   );

   reg [K:1] a;
   reg [K:1] b;

   //'[i+1]' busses that wrap.
   // eg, for a 4-bit bus...
   // a[i]:        a[4],a[3],a[2],a[1] (obviously...)
   // a_wrap[i]:   a[1],a[4],a[3],a[2] 
   wire [K:1] mask_wrap    = { mask[1],mask[K:2] };
   wire [K:1] a_wrap       = { a[1], a[K:2] };
   wire [K:1] current_wrap = { current[1], current[K:2] };

   integer i;
   always @( * ) begin
      for( i=1; i<=K; i=i+1 ) begin
         a[i] = ~current_wrap[i] && b[i];
         b[i] = a_wrap[i] || mask_wrap[i];
         next[i] = ~a[i] && mask_wrap[i];
      end
   end


endmodule
```

(Disclaimer: linted but not simulated)

Comment: I probably should mention that this is Verilog-2001.  And that I prefer my buses to go from [K-1:0]...

Comment: Fair enough. The bus indexing probably should be zero-based. Thank you for the excellent answer.